# Table not displayed properly when table data is hidden

Tags: html, css

[image]

As displayed in image, Table structure is coming properly in mozilla but collapsing in crome.
Data in the table will be added on select of Select option as

[image]

tried with table-layout: fixed but not working

Comment: give some code,lets see what you have been doing so far

Comment: Give `min-height` to table <tr> should do the trick

Comment: You can use [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/pen/) to show you code.

Comment: min-height worked..Its coming properly now. Thanks @Jaykishan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `min-height` CSS to `<tr>`, other wise browser will render tr with their default min-height.

Answer (score 1):

two ways i can suggest you for this thing,

1) Try by Wrapping your cell content inside Div and set height and width of div tag(in %x)

2) set min-height:%x in CSS to < tr>..